# Python3 Linux and Selenium (Edge)

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
browser = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
browser.get("http://www.abv.bg")
abv_output = browser.page_source
print(abv_output)
```

The linux machine is only CLI without GUI
Similar code works on my Windows 11. Any thoughts?
I receive following error:

```
    root@pinger-st:/sbin# python3 simo.py

[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current edge version is 115.0.1901
[WDM] - Get LATEST edgedriver version for 115.0.1901 Edge
[WDM] - Driver [/root/.wdm/drivers/edgedriver/linux64/115.0.1901.183/msedgedriver] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simo.py", line 5, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/edge/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```